# Program to find root of a third degree polynomial in c (Sidi's Method)

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program to find the root of a third degree polynomial function using Sidi's method which is similar to Newton's Method and the Secant Method. The only difference is using the interpolated polynomial instead of the derivative of the function. I also have to test my code with 50 guesses, and I have tried writing the code but when I execute it nothing happens. This is my code

```
 double f(double x)
{
    return ((3*x*x*x)-(6*x*x)-(6*x)-5);//polynomial equation
}
double y(double z)
{
    return ((17.8*z*z*z)-(34.5*z*z)+(199.7*z)+30);//interpolation equation
}
double dy (float z)
{
    return ((53.4*z*z)-(69*z)+199.7);//derivative of interpolation equation
}
 main()
{
    double i;
    int maxitr = 10;
    int itr;
    double a;
    double b;
    double maxdec = 0.000001;
       for(i=1; i<= 50; i++){
            printf("Input guess ");
            scanf("%lf", i);
        for(itr = 1; itr < maxitr; itr++){
            a = f(i) / dy(i);
            b = i - a;
            if(fabs(a) < maxdec){
                printf("root: %lf", b);
                return 0;
            }
        i = b;
        }
       }
```

Comment: Is ten max iterations enough to converge?  Try breaking when you do and printing your result and the number of iterations outside the loop.

Comment: should it be fabs(b-a) ??

Comment: Minor note: code will usually generate more accurate results with `(3*x*x*x)-(6*x*x)-(6*x)-5` --> `((3*x - 6)*x - 6)*x) - 5`  - also less chance of over/underflow.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you. My program solves this equation f(x)=x^7-1000 = 0.You can add your equation by editing the `void f(double x[],int x1,int x2)` function. Also you add whatever else you want more.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

void f(double x[],int x1,int x2);

int main()
{
 double x[50];
 int x1,x2;

 printf("Enter x1:\n");
 scanf("%d",&x1);
 printf("Enter x2:\n");
 scanf("%d",&x2);
 printf("\nCalculating....\n");
 f(x,x1,x2);

 return 0; 
}

void f(double x[],int x1,int x2)
{
 // Assuming Equation is x^7 - 1000
 // you can edit this code to keep your 
 // own equation

 int i,prec=10000;
 double a,b,num;
 double denom,d1,d2;
 x[0] = 0.00;      //let's start with index 1 instead of 0
 x[1] = x1;
 x[2] = x2;

 printf("x[2]:%f\n",x[2]);
 for(i=3;i<=50;i++)
 {
    num = pow(x[i-1],7)-1000;
    d1 =  (pow(x[i-1],7)-1000) - (pow(x[i-2],7)-1000);
    d2 =  (x[i-1] - x[i-2]);
    denom = d1/d2;


    x[i] =  x[i-1] -  num/denom;

    printf("x[%d]:%f\n",i,x[i]);

    a= (long int)(x[i]*prec);
    b= (long int)(x[i-1]*prec);
    if(a == b)
    {
      break;
    }
 }

printf("x[%d]=%f and x[%d]=%f are apprx equal!\n",i-1,x[i-1],i,x[i]);

}
```

Where,

1. `num` is `(x2)^7 - 1000`
2. `d1` is `((x2)^7 - 1000)-((x1)^7-1000)`
3. `d2` is `x2-x1`
4. `denom` is `d1/d2`